# automating the silent installation with auto text field fill

Tags: python

I'm automating the installation of a program with python.
So far I can locate the .msi installer and execute it, and then I can automate all the clicks to go through the installation process.

The thing I'm stuck on is, I can't manage to find a way to fill in the text fields that come up during the installation. For example as your installing a software the installer might prompt you to enter your name, or address etc. How do I do an "autofill" for those text fields by pre-defining strings in my script and inserting them to the text fields as they pop-up?

Comment: How exactly are you doing that? Are you sending mouse events to a window? What is your operating system? Why can't you just send keystroke events to the window in the same way?

Comment: Most windows programs have command line switches for their installers. If your installer has them too, all you need to do is pass them in a command line. If not, there are windows automation tools that can help you with that like pyautogui or sikulix.